# How do I use the default blue annotation for user location rather than my custom annotation?

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkannotation

I have custom annotations on my map and now I want to be able to show the user location as well as the custom annotations. However, when I show the user location it uses the custom annotation rather than the default blue annotation. Is there a way to make the user location use the default?

I get the users location to show using the below:

```
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
map.showsUserLocation = true
```

And the custom annotation is set up using the following:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let reuseIdentifier = "pin"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = false
    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "Marker")

    return annotationView
}
```

Thanks

Comment: why dont you remove if you dont want to use your custom annotation ?

Comment: I want to use my custom annotation for all annotations apart from the one that shows the user's location - when I call showUserLocation it naturally uses this custom annotation

Comment: is it okay for you using different custom annotations then ?

Comment: I have found that I need to check the annotation that comes into viewFor to check it is of type MKUserLocation - if it is then I simply return nil instead.

Comment: adding my answer if it make helps let me know

Comment: it was achieved using the following: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61785563/how-to-set-a-custom-annotations-for-all-points-except-for-user-location

Answer (score 2):

Do it like below :

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    yourCustomAnnotation = CustomPointAnnotation()
    yourCustomAnnotation.pinCustomImageName = "Marker"
    yourCustomAnnotation.coordinate = location

    yourCustomAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: yourCustomAnnotation, reuseIdentifier: "pin")
    map.addAnnotation(yourCustomAnnotationView.annotation!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dealing with the same problem. Use this check at the top of your "viewFor annotation" delegate method:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard annotation as? MKUserLocation != mapView.userLocation else { return }
```

This will prevent from customize your User location

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in your MKMapViewDelegate like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation { return nil }
    
    // return custom views for other annotations...
}
```

Comment: That is the correct solution. That works in my productive app for many years now. Who voted this down?